# Login and register functionality not working after i deployed nextjs app on vercel

Tags: environment-variables, next.js, vercel

I was done building a nextjs app and tested the build version on my localhost, it was working perfectly fine but when I tried to login or register on the deployed version on vercel it doesn't work. I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input error and a 404 error for the API route.
I've double checked the env variables. Here the code for the the api request in my context

```
AuthContext.js
  // Register user
  const register = async (user) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${NEXT_URL}/api/register`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    if (res.ok) {
      setUser(data.user);
      router.push("/account/dashboard");
    } else {
      setError(data.message);
      setError(null);
    }
  };

  // Login user
  const login = async ({ email: identifier, password }) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${NEXT_URL}/api/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        identifier,
        password,
      }),
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    if (res.ok) {
      setUser(data.user);
      router.push("/account/dashboard");
    } else {
      setError(data.message);
      setError(null);
    }
  };

  // Logout user
  const logout = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${NEXT_URL}/api/logout`, {
      method: "POST",
    });

    if (res.ok) {
      setUser(null);
      router.push("/");
    }
  };

  // Check if user is logged in
  const checkUserLoggedIn = async (user) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${NEXT_URL}/api/user`);
    const data = await res.json();

    if (res.ok) {
      setUser(data.user);
    } else {
      setUser(null);
    }
  };
```

API route

```
api/login.js
import cookie from 'cookie'
import { API_URL } from '@/config/index'

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { identifier, password } = req.body

    const strapiRes = await fetch(`${API_URL}/auth/local`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        identifier,
        password,
      }),
    })

    const data = await strapiRes.json()

    if (strapiRes.ok) {
      // Set Cookie
      res.setHeader(
        'Set-Cookie',
        cookie.serialize('token', data.jwt, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
          sameSite: 'strict',
          path: '/',
        })
      )

      res.status(200).json({ user: data.user })
    } else {
      res
        .status(data.statusCode)
        .json({ message: data.message[0].messages[0].message })
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST'])
    res.status(405).json({ message: `Method ${req.method} not allowed` })
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://nextjs-events-app-x.vercel.app/account/login)

Comment: Are you certain the requests are made against the right endpoint when deployed to Vercel? Can you check the logs for your API routes? Also, where do `NEXT_URL` & `API_URL` come from?

Comment: NEXT_URL & API_URL are my environment variables which I included in the vercel deploy, the API_URL points to my strapi backend and the NEXT_URL is my frontend. The post request seems to post to https://nextjs-events-app-x.vercel.app/account/nextjs-events-app.vercel.app/api/login which doesn't seem right cos I don't know if its supposed to append the API_URL to my current domain route

Comment: What value are you setting for `NEXT_URL`? Does it include the `https://` part?

Comment: Yes I have, for both variables

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem, I just had to remove the NEXT_URL.